# Item both in list and not in list

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists in python:

```
list 
ItemNumbersClean
FinalList
```

I want to find, for each item in `ItemNumbersClean`, if it is in `list`. If it is in `list` then to find information from `FinalList` and all it to a new list: `ExcelList`.

This is my code:

```
for l in ItemNumbersClean:
    count += 1
    if l in list:
        for t in FinalList:
            i = t[0]
            if i == l:
                excelList.append([str(i), str(t[1]), str(t[2])])
                match_counter += 1
    elif l not in list:
        not_found_counter += 1
        excelList.append(['not found', 'not found', 'not found'])
```

`ItemNumbersClean` has a length of item numbers.

However when I add my debug counters together (match_counter and not_found_counter) I get 186.

Also `ExcelList` ends up with a length of 186.

As `ItemNumbersClean` only has a length of 151 the only possible way that `excelList` can have a length of more than 151 is if some items in `ItemNumbersClean` are passing both the `if` and `elif` statements.

I can't seem to understand how this is possible, either generally, (an item can't both be in a list and not in a list), or how my code might be causing this.

Comment: No, `l in list` and `l not in list` cannot both be true for a given pair of `l` and `list`.  The `if l in list` block can easily add multiple items to `excelList` depending on the contents of `FinalList`.

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Could you please post some examples of input and desired output?  Also, don't use "list" as the name for a list,since it is the name of a python function.

Comment: @scharette done

Comment: @JoeSmart: match_counter increment should be dedented still to the same level as for?

Comment: It can't pass both `if` and `elif`. Even _if_ both conditions could appy at the same time (and they don't), the `elif` will _only_ be checked if the `if` check failed.

Comment: You probably have to add a `break` to `if i == l:`, otherwise a single item might be added to `FinalList` more than once, which is probably what's going on here.

Comment: Don't name any variables `list`. Shadowing built-ins can cause subtle bugs and surprises later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't pass both the `if` and `elif` statement. Even if both conditions could appy at the same time (and in your case they can't), the `elif` will only be checked if the `if` check failed.

Instead, you probably have to add a `break` after the `if i == l:`, otherwise a single item `l` might be added to `FinalList` more than once, which is probably what's going on here.